# Looking for data or nomenclature that partains to "Smoothness/accuracy" of servo grade gearboxs for roll to roll application

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, servo, nomenclature

I am designing a roll to roll web drive system where having smooth consistent very slow speed is important to quality of the product. I will be using a clearpath servo motor with a gearbox of 20:1 ratio.

It has been recommended to me that I might consider a Hypoid gear reduction for the smoothness characteristics but I cannot find any papers or specifications relating to smoothness of different servo grade gearbox types, nor do I know what this spec might be called.

If someone with more experience could tell me the words I might use to look for information on this that would be really appreciated.

Comment: what is a "web drive system"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conclusion I've come to is to look at a spec called angular transmission accuracy, in conjunction with the backlash, as long as one is lower than my required minimum unexpected positional jump I believe I should be good.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for backlash, the clearance between the gear teeth in mesh. Not sure what a web drive is but if you're looking for smooth as possible motion I'd look at belts and pulleys instead of gears.

Comment: We are preloading the drive so backlash isn't really an issue. I think you'd call it a web drive, its the system that drives a belt of flat material like paper or plastic sheet between a winder and unwinder so that coatings or markings may be put onto the sheet then rerolled for transport. ours needs to have very smooth motion with no cogging from belt teeth entering mesh with pulleys. unfortunately it still needs to be synchronus so something like a flat belt or O ring belt wont really work well.